# What is known about the upper density of torsion elements in finitely generated groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $T\subset G$ be the set of all torsion elements in a finitely generated infinite group $G$, and let $B_n\subset G$ be the closed ball of radius $n$ around $1$ w.r.t. to the word metric for some choice of a finite generating set $S$. Consider the upper density
$$
t_S(G)=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|B_n\cap T|}{|B_n|}.
$$
In the following basic cases $t=t_S$ is independent of $S$:

- $t(G)=0$ if $G$ is torsion-free (trivially)
- $t(G)=1$ if $G$ is a [finitely generated infinite torsion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_problem) (trivially)
- $t(G\ast H)=0$ whenever $t(G)=0$ and $H$ is finite (slighly less obvious, can be shown using [Kurosh's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurosh_subgroup_theorem))

> **Questions**
>
> 1. Is $t_S(G)$ always independent of the choice of a generating set $S$?
> 2. Is the $\limsup$ always a proper limit?
> 3. What is known about the values $t_S\in[0,1]$ that occur?

Comment: The notation is confusing: you should denote it $t_S(G)$ for $S=B_1$. Then Question 1 is whether $t_S(G)$ only depends on $G$. Question 3 asks what values are obtained when $G$ and $S$ vary.

Comment: A 2007 paper by P. Dani (J. Algebra, [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601126)) establishes that for virtually nilpotent groups, $t_S(G)$ only depends on $G$ (hence can be denoted $t(G)$ in this special case), is a genuine limit, and, when $G$ varies, achieves precisely all rational numbers in $[0,1]$ ($1$ if and only if the group is finite) — and more precisely all are achieved by some virtually abelian group.

Comment: @YCor: notation enhanced, thank you

Comment: Just to be precise about the three examples items. 1st item:  $t(G)=0$ if $G$ is torsion free **and infinite** (i.e. nontrivial). 2nd item: for $G$ torsion, $t(G)=1$ (no need to assume $G$ infinite).

Comment: Thanks @YCor, please note: $G$ being infinite is a standing assumption made in the first sentence.